# How to send synchronous response with HTTP Receiver in UFT 11.53

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I am testing a web service that after a request first sends a synchronous response and after some time sends an asynchronous response. I have set it up with a HTTP Request for sending and a HTTP receiver to get the asynchronous message. I do get the response message but the service requires a synchronous ACK message otherwise it will continue to send the message with regular intervals. I cannot figure out how to send this synchronous ACK back to th service. What I can see there is nothing in the GUI to achieve this, but it seems strange that such a common thing shouldn't be possible.
There is no WSDL available so I cannot use that to import it as a server response

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP receiver does return a message with the status code.
Moreover, UFT's HTTP receiver acts as a container, thus you can drag and drop an http call into the receiver and send a specific http call, back to the client that called UFT's receiver

Comment: Thanks. But is it possible to customize rhat response message. The service I am testing requires a responseId in the Sync Ack message. I have slso thought about the possibility  to add something in the receiver container, but what i understand it is not possible to create a synchronous response that way.   The only way out that i van see is to use the onReceive event and code it in c#, but since I'm not a C# hacker I have no idea how to do it. If anyone out there has done anything like it before I would really apreciate a copy of that code